# Implementing function trees in C#

Tags: c#, math, tree

Imagine you have a [function tree](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/77/Genetic_Program_Tree.png) which has a number of nodes which can be either **operator nodes** (unary or binary operators), or **terminal nodes** (constants).

I've just started putting finger to keyboard and I've hit a small snag. I have created a `Node` interface, `Operator:Node`, `BinaryOperator:Operator`, `UnaryOperator:Operator` and `Terminal:Node` constructs.

And here I am with my problem. Do I now create a separate class for every foreseeable function? Do I create a `SinOperator:UnaryOperator` and `CosOperator:UnaryOperator` and `AddOperator:BinaryOperator` and so on? There are quite a few that can be considered if you include forward and inverse trig functions and their hyperbolic cousins.

Alternatively, I can just leave it at Binary and Unary operators and pass in a delegate which evaluates that node's value based on it's child nodes.

```
var sinOperator = new UnaryOperator(
                    childNode,
                    delegate()
                    {
                      return Math.Sin(childNode.GetValue());
                    });
```

But then there's not really anything stopping me from putting all sorts of crazy stuff in the delegate, breaking the whole concept of it just being an operator.

*Note: yes I realise that there are only a few **operators** (+-*/^√), and that sin/cos are actually **functions**... but for the purposes of this project we can assume that it is an operator*

So how would you structure this in C#?

Comment: "Do I now create a separate class for every foreseeable function?" No, you create just enough classes to meet your requirements. You *do* have stated requirements, don't you? If you don't, how will you know when you've finished?

Comment: @AakashM I am running my own computational experiments for genetic programming optimising function trees. This is experimentation for my PhD. So in other words, I don't have stated requirements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you take a look at how [Linq.Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.aspx) work? It's an existing model of this (and the whole .NET language) in C#.

Here you have a [nice example of a Derivation program](http://blogs.southworks.net/dgeffner/2011/09/26/implementing-complex-case-analysis/) implemented using Linq.Expressions (You can check how it handles operators, sines, cosines, etc...)

Answer (score 0):

Let us try to define `SinOperator:UnaryOperator`

Assuming that you have made `GetValue` virtual on `Node`, `SinOperator` should just provide an implementation of `GetValue` which computes Sin of a number by operating on the operand obtained by computing the single child node it expects.

This task of 'computing the single child node' is redundant for each `UnaryOperator` and hence should essentially belong to `UnaryOperator` class and `SinOperator` must itself override a `Eval` method accepting a single `double` argument and returning `double`.

```
abstract class UnaryOperator:Operator //specializes GetValue
{
    //....Rest of the implementatiom
    //....
    public sealed override double GetValue()
    {
        return Eval(_childNode.GetValue());  
    }

    protected abstract double Operate(double arg);
}

class SinOperator:UnaryOperator
{
    public override double Eval(double arg)
    {
        return Math.Sin(arg);          
    }    
}
```

Note here how SinOperator has deviated from a Node's goal of 'Getting Value in a specialized way'. Instead it has changed its responsibility to 'evaluating value'. This is an entirely new responsibility and does not seem to belong to the original inheritance chain.

So how to go about it? Answer is composition (can be viewed as UnaryOperator 'has an' algorithm to compute a unary function).

```
interface UnaryFunction
{
   double Eval(double arg);
}

class UnaryOperator:Operator //specializes GetValue
{
    private UnaryFunction _evaluator; //For Sin this is SinFunction

    //....Rest of the implementatiom
    //....
    public sealed override double GetValue()
    {
        return _evaluator.Eval(_childNode.GetValue());  
    }
}

class SinFuntion:UnaryFunction
{
    public override double Eval(double arg)
    {
        return Math.Sin(arg);          
    }    
}
```

And how to obtain a SinOperator? I would suggest using a factory so that creation of a UnaryOperator tied to Sinfunction can be centralized and is always consistent. Later on if you hit upon a new faster way of computing `Sine` than `Math.Sin` you can easily create a `SinFunctionFast` class and in your factory plant this class instead of `SinFunction`.

In languages like Java you would have probably gone like this but, since C# allows for delegates, you can go with delegates to avoid defining a lot of function classes. 
(delegates in any way are a short hand of defining a class such as SinFunction).

Having said this, I would like to caution you against your current thought:

```
var sinOperator = new UnaryOperator(
                    childNode,
                    delegate()
                    {        
                      return Math.Sin(childNode.GetValue());
                    });
```

To guard against any arbitrary delegate, you should pass the Math.Sin itself to the delegate and `UnaryOperator` should expect a unary delegate (i.e. accepting single argument of type double and returning a double).

```
var sinOperator = new UnaryOperator(childNode, Math.Sin);

//In UnaryOperator Class
public override double GetValue()
{
     return _OpDelegate(_childNode.GetValue());
}
```

Recommendation to use a factory for creating different operators stand in this case as well.

One potential disadvantage of using delegates here is that in C# there is no way of preventing supply of a multicast delegate while in your case you need a Uni-cast delegate only. Also according to [Microsoft's guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173173.aspx) (especially note the example of `IComparable`) you should chose interface rather than a delegate for this particular implementation.

One advantage of uni-cast delegates over interfaces is that they are just a notch faster. But in order to gain any conceivable performance gain from this you will need a huge function tree with a lot of operators.